# Variable passed by 'docker run' to CMD of Dockerfile is not resolved

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run

Can anyone explain why is the environment variable passed by

```bash
docker run --rm -it -e APP_PORT=80 -p 8080:80 my_container <image-id>
```

to CMD in Dockerfile is not resolved in following cases:

```bash
...
ARG APP_PORT
ENV APP_PORT=${APP_PORT}
...
CMD ['gunicorn', "-b", "0.0.0.0:${APP_PORT}", "main:app"]  # DOES NOT WORK!
CMD ['gunicorn', "-b", "0.0.0.0:$APP_PORT", "main:app"]    # DOES NOT WORK!

CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo 0.0.0.0:$APP_PORT"]                 # WORKS!

CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$APP_PORT main:app                 # WORKS!
```

`DOES NOT WORK!` means I get the error: `Container log - Error: '$APP_PORT' is not a valid port number.`

Comment: In the exec form `CMD [...]` nothing runs a shell and nothing expands the `$APP_PORT` variable reference, that string gets passed literally as an argument to the program.  In the shell form `CMD ...` Docker wraps the string in `sh -c` and that shell expands variable references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 forms of the CMD statement, like you show.

One is the *exec* form, which is the one that doesn't work. It's usually preferred because it doesn't start a shell first to run the command, so it uses a little less resources.

The other is the *shell* form, which is the one that works. The reason that it works is that you need a shell to replace environment variables in a command. The shell form starts up a shell, that then executes your command.

As you've seen in your `echo` example, you can also make the exec form work by running the shell manually.

You can read more about the 2 forms here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

In short, the examples that don't work, don't work because there's no shell to insert the value of the environment variable in the command.